# Removing a closure from an array

Tags: swift

Removing a closure from an array but not using it causes compiler error "Expression resolves to an unused function". Is there a good way to avoid this, other than assigning the function to a throwaway variable?

```
typealias StringFunction = () -> String  
var list = [StringFunction]()            
list.append({ "Hello World!" })          
let hi = list[0]()                       // "Hello World!"
list.removeAtIndex(0)                    // Expression resolves to an unused function
let _ = list.removeAtIndex(0)            // Works
```

Comment: Weird, `list.removeAtIndex(0)` works ok in a Playground (6.3.2), no error.

Comment: @EricD. That's because the playground takes and uses the value (in the right hand margin), whereas regular code does not.

Comment: Oh, ok, Thanks a lot for the precision, good to know.

Comment: `list.removeRange(0...0)` avoids the error, and has the added advantage of looking like an emoticon :)  (not a serious suggestion…)

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity Hah, I actually considered it but I loathe repetition. :)

Comment: Define `prefix operator ✖ {} ; prefix func ✖<T>(ignore: T) { }` and then write `✖list.removeAtIndex(0)` (not serious either :)

Answer (score 1):

Assigning the result of the expression to a throwaway variable *is* the correct way to do that. In fact, this is the idiomatic way to treat unused results in Swift.

Hence (as noted in the comments of another answer) the correct solution the is:

```
typealias StringFunction = () -> String
var list = [StringFunction]()
list.append({ "Hello World!" })
let hi = list[0]()
_ = list.remove(at: 0) // Note there's no need for `let`
```

Doing so not only makes your code clearer about your intent (i.e. it indicates that you definitely don't need the result of the method), but also helps the compiler perform all sorts of useful optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

This compiled for me:

```
typealias StringFunction = () -> String
var list = [StringFunction]()
list.append({ "Hello World!" })
let hi = list[0]()                       // "Hello World!"
list.removeAtIndex(0)()
```

Although this does call the function. (thanks Martin R)

Comment: But this would *call* the just removed function (which might have unwanted side effects for more general functions).

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I didn't think that @Blix's function had side effects, though, given that his original solution would call the function as well.

Comment: But `let _ = list.removeAtIndex(0)` does not call the function.

Comment: Why is it usually a warning when you don't use the return value, but in this case it's an error? Such an annoying mistake, but Martin R's solution works.