# Compiler complains that 'Expression resolved to unused function' when removing index in array of functions

Tags: ios, swift

I created this test case with 2 types and as expected the 'Int' case works. The Callback one doesn't. Not sure why this is happening. I've been trying lots of things. I may be missing something obvious?

```
typealias Type1 = Int
typealias Type2 = ([AnyObject?]) -> Void

class Test {
    private var cb1: [Type1]
    private var cb2: [Type2]

    init() {
        cb1 = [Type1](count: 2, repeatedValue: 0)
        cb2 = [Type2](count: 2, repeatedValue: { _ in })
    }

    func removeAtIndex(index: Int) {
        cb1.removeAtIndex(index)
        cb2.removeAtIndex(index)
    }

}
```

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Yes: 'Expression resolved to unused function' at this line: cb2.removeAtIndex(index)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625594/removing-a-closure-from-an-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Resolving to an unused function` is trying to tell you that you have an expression that is returning a function type, but you never call it

So,you just need try to use it

```
typealias Type1 = Int
typealias Type2 = ([AnyObject?]) -> Void

class Test {
private var cb1: [Type1]
private var cb2: [Type2]

init() {
    cb1 = [Type1](count: 2, repeatedValue: 0)
    cb2 = [Type2](count: 2, repeatedValue: { _ in })
}

func removeAtIndex(index: Int) {
    cb1.removeAtIndex(index)
  let result = cb2.removeAtIndex(index)
}
}
```

Comment: Why is 'cb1.removeAtIndex(index)' not stating the same? Is this operating mutating my array?

Comment: Because,`cb1.removeAtIndex(index)` return Int,and `cb2.removeAtIndex(index)` return block,if you return block,and do not use it,you will get the error you see